# Adding to virtual function in derived class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a class `pawn` which inherits from `piece`: piece has a function `moveTo` declared as below:

```
public virtual void moveTo(Coord newLoc)
{
    Coord origLoc = location;
    Transform transform = gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>();
    Coord transCoord = newLoc - location;

    if (LogicMaster.currentBoard[newLoc].piece != null) { 
        if (LogicMaster.currentBoard[transCoord].piece.targeted) { 
            UnityEngine.Object.Destroy(LogicMaster.currentBoard[transCoord].actor);
            LogicMaster.currentBoard[transCoord].actor = null;
        }
    }

    if (LogicMaster.currentBoard[newLoc].actor == null)
    {
        Vector3 transVector = new Vector3();

        transVector.x = transform.position.x + transCoord.x * Constants.oneRight.x;
        transVector.z = transform.position.z + transCoord.y * Constants.oneForward.y;
        transVector.y = transform.position.y;
        transform.position =  transVector;

        LogicMaster.currentBoard[newLoc].actor = gameObject;
        LogicMaster.currentBoard[newLoc].piece = this;
        LogicMaster.currentBoard[newLoc].piece.location = newLoc;
        LogicMaster.currentBoard[this].actor = null;
        LogicMaster.currentBoard[this].piece = null;
        LogicMaster.selectedPiece = null;
        LogicMaster.pieceSelected = false;
        LogicMaster.currentBoard.resetColours();
        LogicMaster.currentBoard.hideMarkers();
        LogicMaster.whiteTurn = !LogicMaster.whiteTurn;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to implement an override within the `pawn` class that implements the code within `moveTo` but then adds some onto the end? Otherwise I assume it's simply a copy and paste job.

Thanks.

Comment: `base.moveTo(...); // the rest of your code`?

Comment: Also take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152996/how-to-properly-override-a-base-class-method#answer-3153052 . The "OnSomething" pattern is very useful in inheritance scenarios.

Comment: why dont you just extract the bit every child also needs and create a seperate function? as general rule of thumb, if you would need to write something more than once, make it a function. its also more descriptive to call Beat(pawn) and idk RegisterWithTile(pawn) than calling base.MoveTo(newloc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As CodeCaster mentions you can override the method and call base.MoveTo(..) and afterwards add your own logic.

Example

The base class:

```
public class CodeFirstInstallationService : IInstallationService
{
    public virtual void InstallData(string defaultUserEmail,
        string defaultUserPassword, bool installSampleData = true)
    {
        // Doing basic logic
    }
}
```

The class deriving from the base:

```
public class MyInstallationService : CodeFirstInstallationService
{
    public override void InstallData(string defaultUserEmail,
        string defaultUserPassword, bool installSampleData = true)
    {
        // Let the base class do it´s install logic
        base.InstallData(defaultUserEmail, defaultUserPassword, installSampleData);

        // Do my own logic
        // Install flux capacitor etc
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for.